# ViewPager - Animate TextView on swipe

Tags: java, android

My swipe screen work perfect, it has 3 fragments with few text  views per fragment.

I animated good in FlipView component, but I found that is better to use ViewPager for my problem.

My problem is that I don't know where to handle fragments on swipe.

When swipe I want to know from wich fragment on which fragment it goes.

Because when I swipe from FragmentA to FragmentB i want text box on FragmentB animate from Left to right, when I return from FragmentB to FragmentA I want to animate text box from Right to left on FragmentA.

All that animation I know how to do, but don't know where to catch from and to which fragment I'm going.

It's not problem to animate each fragment in fragment code, but I don't know from which fragment I goes on him and then I don't know on which side text animates. :)

My code looks like this:

Activity:

```
ViewPager viewPager;
int numberOfViewPagerChildren = 3;
int lastIndexOfViewPagerChildren = numberOfViewPagerChildren - 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_tips);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    final LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable) viewPager.getBackground();

    background.getDrawable(0).setAlpha(0); // this is the lowest drawable
    background.getDrawable(1).setAlpha(0);
    background.getDrawable(2).setAlpha(255); // this is the upper one

    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            int index = (Integer) view.getTag();
            Drawable currentDrawableInLayerDrawable;
            currentDrawableInLayerDrawable = background.getDrawable(index);

            if (position <= -1 || position >= 1) {
                currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha(0);
            } else if (position == 0) {
                currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha(255);
            } else {
                currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha((int) (255 - Math.abs(position * 255)));
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

MyAdapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{


    int numberOfViewPagerChildren = 3;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(i==0)
        {
            fragment=new FragementA();
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentB();
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfViewPagerChildren;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        if(object instanceof FragementA){

            view.setTag(2);

        }
        if(object instanceof FragmentB){

            view.setTag(1);
        }
        if(object instanceof FragmentC){

            view.setTag(0);
        }
        return super.isViewFromObject(view, object);
    }
}
```

And one Fragment, let it be FragmentA:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_a,container,false);

        return v;
    }
}
```